# What attribute do incorporeal creatures use for strength skills?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, ability-scores, incorporeal

The SRD clearly states that incorporeal creatures have no Strength score, and use their Dexterity modifier for both melee and ranged attacks. However, what about Strength-based skills? Can a spook even use skills like Jump? Do they get a bonus from Strength (+0) or does Dexterity replace it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm):

> The modifier for a nonability is +0.

The [incorporeal subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) makes no mention of exceptions for strength-based skills, so in the absence of any text to the contrary (such as exists for melee attacks), you simply use your strength modifier (+0) for any strength-based skill checks you make.